# Count visible rows from a filter result set that meet 3 criterea

Tags: excel, filter

Not sure I'm doing this right, but I have a need to count only visible cells from a filter result that meet three criteria. I am trying the following formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET(F10,ROW(F10:F3153)-ROW(F10),0)),(F10:F3153="North America"),SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET(G10,ROW(G10:G3153)-ROW(G10),0)),(G10:G3153="US Comm/CSI Market"),SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET(K10,ROW(K10:K3153)-ROW(K10),0)),(K10:K3153="Won")+0)
```

, but though the syntax appears correct (Excel doesn't balk at the formula). it is not returning a correct result. What I need to do, is sort through a filter result set, and count the number of resulting visible rows that meet three criteria in different columns in the same row. If all three are met, it counts it. HELP?

Comment: Do you happen to have Office 365? This would also be easier if you just told us what the criteria is rather us deconstructing your formula

Comment: I do have Office 365. yes.  I'm sorry.  I need to sort through a filter results set in a data file that goes from Row 10-Row 3153.  In the resulting filter set, I need to count the number of rows in which in the same row column F="North America" + Column G="US Comm/CSI Market" and column K="Won".  If all three of those criterea are met in one row in the visible rows, then it counts that row.

Comment: What is the filter that is applied? You can use the `FILTER` function to recreate the resultant data set since ignoring hidden rows is a pain, at least for me it has been

Comment: The data set is sales pipeline data that includes multiple business units.  The filter isolates the data file to one business unit.  I'm afraid I can't go into much more detail than that in a public forum.

Comment: This is what sample data is for.

Answer (score 0):

If you have  <kbd>Office 365</kbd>  you can use the `FILTER` function to output an array of rows that meet all of your criteria. You can then just `COUNTA` the array to get your final count.

Note that each of the criteria you provided is essentially a filter so if your data is filtered by other things that you have not shared (business units) then just add that to this equation as a filter. I added `Other Filter` to demonstrate the point which you can just sub out for your business unit(s)

```
G7 = COUNTA(FILTER(A2:A8,(A2:A8=G3)*(B2:B8=G4)*(C2:C8=G5)*(D2:D8=G6)))
```

---

[image]

---

In this example the equation counts how many rows meet the 4 criteria listed  below (3):

```
1. Country = North America
2. Market = US Comm/CSI Market
3. Status = Won
4. Other Filter = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try it please?

```
 =SUMPRODUCT((G10:G3153="US Comm/CSI Market")*(K10:K3153="Won")*(F10:F3153="North America")*(SUBTOTAL(103,OFFSET(F10,ROW(F10:F3153)-MIN(ROW(F10:F3153)),0))))
```

Useful link:

https://exceljet.net/formula/count-visible-rows-only-with-criteria

Comment: Works PERFECTLY!  EXACTLY what I was looking for - THANK YOU!